# how to find and replace any thing between <a href=""></a> in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to find and delete in vs code.

for example

```
href ="/file/image1"
```

and the second instance is

```
href ="/file/image2"
```

I want to delete the href in between anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just open file with your href in Visual Studio Code and delete, replace or do whatever you want.